# How to rebuild an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that's like this:

```
[
    [ "bar1", "bar2" ],
    [ "bar1", "bar2" ],
    [ "bar1", "bar2" ]      
]
```

I'd like to rebuild with named properties, like this:

```
[
    { foo1: "bar1", foo2: "bar2" },
    { foo1: "bar1", foo2: "bar2" },
    { foo1: "bar1", foo2: "bar2" }
]
```

Currently I am manually looping through the array and building a new one. But is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `.map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map. But you have to iterate either way.

Comment: You can replace text in array with array. You don't need to create second array and rewrite it.

Comment: ^^ what Felix said -> http://jsfiddle.net/4MhJz/

Comment: @adeneo this is great, thank you! feel free to add this as an answer, I'll make it official

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I am manually looping through the array and building a new one. But is there a better way to do this?

No. Only more concise notation, using the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr2 = arr1.map(function(a) {
    return {foo1: a[0], foo2: a[1]};
});
```